# How do i use scrolltop correctly so that it triggers two times?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to change the the css of my logo, when it reaches a certain point on the website, and then backagain after the specific section is finished. 
But im having trouble doing it correctly. any help?

I have already made this scroll function but it only works one way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 600 ) {
      $(".uk-responsive-height").css("display", "none");
      $(".uk-logo-inverse").css("display", "block");
   } else if( $(this).scrollTop() > 999) {
      $(".uk-logo-inverse").css("display", "none");
      $(".uk-responsive-height").css("display", "block");
   }
  });
});
```

This worked for me. I don't know if this is the best way. I tweaked the numbers to fit better for my page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
     if( $(this).scrollTop() > 1700 ) {
       $(".uk-responsive-height").css("display", "block");
       $(".uk-logo-inverse").css("display", "none");
    return;
 }
 if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
    $(".uk-responsive-height").css("display", "none");
    $(".uk-logo-inverse").css("display", "block");
 }
 if ( $(this).scrollTop() < 600) {
    $(".uk-responsive-height").css("display", "block");
    $(".uk-logo-inverse").css("display", "none");
  }
   });
 });
```

Comment: add else condition .

Comment: Try `offsetTop()`. It checks offset relative to its parent. Whenever you cross that value, it'll trigger the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check firstly highest `scrollTop()` and interrupt function after that

```
if( $(this).scrollTop() > 999 ) {
    $(".uk-logo-inverse").css("display", "none");
    $(".uk-responsive-height").css("display", "block");

    return;
} 

if( $(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
    $(".uk-responsive-height").css("display", "none");
    $(".uk-logo-inverse").css("display", "block");
}
```

After this comment

> Maybe i need to say this. There is two logos, one is normal white and the other one is black. This code nearly works but starts to show both logos. I only need it ".uk-logo-inversed to be display block between 600-1000 after that it should be removed, unless back on those specific pixels

try this

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1000) {
    $(".uk-logo-inversed").css("display", "block");
    $(".uk-responsive-height").css("display", "none");
} else {
    $(".uk-logo-inversed").css("display", "none");
    $(".uk-responsive-height").css("display", "block");
}
```

or solution with less code

```
$(".uk-logo-inversed")[$(this).scrollTop() > 600 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1000 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
$(".uk-responsive-height")[$(this).scrollTop() > 600 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1000 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
```

Comment: `scrollTop() > 600` condition will be executed first no matter in which order you place the code.

Comment: Yes, it will be executed first, but in his code `scrollTop() > 999` will be never executed because it's in else if

Comment: Maybe i need to say this. There is two logos, one is normal white and the other one is black. This code nearly works but starts to show both logos. I only need it ".uk-logo-inversed to be display block between 600-1000 after that it should be removed, unless back on those specific pixels

Comment: As @Sylwek mentioned, `scrollTop() > 999` is never getting executed. Try what he has suggested.

Comment: The second and third code, did not work for me. They completly removed the logo's :) But thanks for the help.